# How do I use df.str.replace() only for complete matches?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace values in my `df`, but only if the values are a complete match, not partial. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam', 'Roger', 'Anna'],
                   'City':['Los Santos', 'Montreal', 'Los', 'Berlin', 'Glasgow']})

print(df)
```

```
    Name        City
0   Mark  Los Santos
1  Laura    Montreal
2   Adam         Los
3  Roger      Berlin
4   Anna     Glasgow
```

I want to replace *Los* by *Los Santos* but if I do it the intuitive way, it results in this:

```
df['City'].str.replace('Los', 'Los Santos')
```

```
Out[121]: 
0    Los Santos Santos
1             Montreal
2           Los Santos
3               Berlin
4              Glasgow
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Obviously, I don't want *Los Santos Santos*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), because [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by default replace by substrings:

```
df['City'] = df['City'].replace('Los', 'Los Santos')
```

Comment: you mean `series.str.replace()` replaces substrings?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
df['City'].str.replace('.*Los$', 'Los Santos')
```

---

```
0    Los Santos
1      Montreal
2    Los Santos
3        Berlin
4       Glasgow
Name: City, dtype: object
```